# Flask + Jinja2 Script imports

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server, jinja2

I'm having an issue when using Flask and it's templates when importing Scripts and Stylesheets. I searched everywhere how to do it, and none of them solved my problem.
This is my project's structure: 
https://i.gyazo.com/f746c58499cbbafa11b023eecb316b15.png
This is how I defined Flask's configuration:

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            template_folder="../web/templates",
            static_folder="../web/static",
            static_url_path=''
)
```

And this is how i'm importing the scripts :

```
<script src={{ url_for('static', filename='/js/home.js') }}></script>
```

And this is the msg I get :

> Falló la carga de  con fuente “http://localhost:5000/js/home.js”.

(Basically says that it failed loading that script)

I already read the Quickstart guide from Flask.
I tried creating a "static" folder in the project's root and not setting anything on the config. Tried to change the static folder everywhere on my project.

Can anyone help me solve this? I'm new to Flask and Jinja, but have been searching the whole day and can't make it work.

NOTE : The path for the templates work, my templates work fine, except for .js and .css imports.

Comment: Please consider posting your code bits instead of screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm new to posting in SO.

Comment: In which folder does your `.py` file lives and where do you run it from?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f44dda71de5b4c746cf7728433fdf445.png 
This is the project structure. It's being ran from the __init__ inside "controladores", and i'm executing it via IDE (pyCharm)

Comment: I have to ask... what do the file structure inside `web/static/js` look like.

Comment: It looks like this : https://i.gyazo.com/2eaf85e04b967760ab81a609bc3b5599.png
Just the js files.

Comment: Did you create it as a Flask project? Try running `flask routes` in the terminal. You should see this route `static    GET      /<path:filename>`

Comment: I just did it, and here's the output for static :
static                                             HEAD,OPTIONS,GET     /[filename]

Comment: What flask version are you using?

Comment: Flask==1.0.2 according to 'pip freeze' (I downloaded it with pip)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove starting '/' from `<script src={{ url_for('static',filename='/js/home.js') }}.`

so change it to `<script src={{ url_for('static',filename='js/home.js') }}.`

your project structure should look like this:

- MyFlaskApp/templates/home.html
- MyFlaskApp/static/js/home.js
- MyFlaskApp/app.py

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src={{ url_for('static',filename='js/home.js') }}> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.js**

```
alert("hello");
```